# Listening to file change events in a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there any way to listen to file changes on disk inside a Chrome Packaged App?

[Documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) doesn't mention anything about file changes. Even Chrome Development Team's own [Text Editor app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/text-app) is not showing changes automatically on file changes.

Do I have to maintain my own dirty checking loop with an JavaScript interval?

Comment: FWIW my local editor (vi) doesn't do this for me, either.  Though I do have an option set on my vi gui that when its window brought into focus it checks all files for changes.  It works well enough in practice, and perhaps that will suffice for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have an API for this unfortunately. There is a long standing bug about adding it [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148873).